# R: How to find grep patterns in string, in the same order as the pattern

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a set of strings, and a set of patterns that I want to look up in the strings.

I know that the patterns exist somewhere there, I just want them to be returned in same order as mentioned in the pattern variable:

Reproducible code:

```
my_strings <- c("I see trees of green", 
               "red roses too",
               "I see them blossom",
               "for me and you") 

my_patterns <- "blossom|green|red"

grep (my_patterns, my_strings, value = TRUE)
```

It returns:

> [1] "I see trees of green" "red roses too"       "I see them blossom"

I don't want it to return this, instead I want it to return:

> [1] "I see them blossom" "I see trees of green" "red roses too"

Since this is the order they where mentioned in at `my_patterns` variable.

How can I achieve this efficiently?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you don't define *patterns* but *one* pattern which is "blosso OR green OR red".
Then, your `grep` goes through your strings and return every value, in the same order, where it meets one of the 3 words.

Instead, you need to define 3 patters and loop on them, for example:

```r
my_strings <- c("I see trees of green", 
               "red roses too",
               "I see them blossom",
               "for me and you") 
my_patterns <- c("blosso","green","red")
sapply(my_patterns, function(x) grep(x, my_strings, value = TRUE))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Suggest this instead which also works  if there are different numbers of matches per pattern and starts with the data in the question: `pats <- strsplit(my_patterns, "\\|")[[1]];
unlist(lapply(pats, grep, my_strings, value = TRUE)`)

Comment: Thanks Jrm, that helped, I also had to filter off empty returned values (i.e. when it returns $`xxxx` character(0) for some values), I used Filter(length, sapply_expression).